# How do you make the Withered animatronic material from FNaF2 in Blender Cycles?

Tags: node-editor

Okay,I saw on Reddit that a person has found the material used for the withered animatronics in FNaF2 which was rendered in 3DS Max and I was wondering if anyone can help me find out how to make the exact same material except in Blender 3D.
[image]

This is the material I was talking about. It was rendered in 3DS Max and I need to make the exact same material in Blender. If you can help it'll be very nice and I'll give you all a big thumbs up for your hard work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a texture to create the bump map, and control the bump level using strength.

[image]

Comment: I actually managed to create a Blender Cycles node that can simulate this perfectly.